# Product attribute label not showing correctly

Tags: product, attributes, custom-attributes

Any help greatly received - I have a configurable product (trousers) with three attributes, waist, leg and colour.  When this displays on the product page the drop downs are fine but I get the labels showing leg, leg, waist instead of waist, leg and colour e.g. visit http://tuffstuff-workwear.co.uk/060814/tuffstuff-trouser-extreme-1024

Comment: Check again the values in the backend. Maybe you added a label for a specific store view. I'm almost sure that this is the problem because in the `spConfig` variable, the one that's in charge of managing the configurable attributes dependencies there is this `var spConfig = new Product.Config({"attributes":{"93":{"id":"93","code":"color","label":"Leg","options"....`. So the label for Color is still `Leg`. Also check one of your translation files just in case.

Answer (score 1):

Open your attributes is Admin / Catalog / Attributes / Manage attributes and check the attribute labels.

I'm sure the labels are set wrong.